# Stream output to different loggers based on output level

Tags: python, logging, stdout, stderr, sys

I am trying to send the system output in Python to two different logs.
But, despite the fact that I have specified two different files with its own logging levels, the two outputs go to the same file.
But, if I only call to one of them, the logging error redirects the output correctly.

```
class StreamToLogger(object):
    def __init__(self, logger, log_level=logging.INFO):
        self.logger = logger
        self.log_level = log_level
        self.linebuf = ''
    def write(self, buf):
        for line in buf.rstrip().splitlines():
            self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip())
    def flush(self):
        pass


def launch_logger(filename,level):
    if level == 'INFO':
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s',filename=filename,filemode='a')
        global stdout_logger
        stdout_logger = logging.getLogger('STDOUT')
        sys.stdout = StreamToLogger(stdout_logger, logging.INFO)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR,format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s',filename=filename,filemode='a')
        global stderr_logger
        stderr_logger = logging.getLogger('STDERR')
        sys.stderr = StreamToLogger(stderr_logger, logging.ERROR)

launch_logger('logs/manager_info.log','INFO')
launch_logger('logs/manager_error.log','ERROR')
print('loggers initialised')
```

Any clue about why is this happening?
Thank you.

Comment: In case you have to debug a problem it's going to be a horror to reconstruct the sequence of log entries if you split them into multiple files by severity.

Comment: @KlausD I'm not agree with you, I only want to put the system error out to a file, so if anything not controlled crash, I know that I must go to the error log, everything else, as stdout is redirected to the main info log.

Comment: Then you put message which have *at least* a certain severity into on file. This is common practice and that is why it can be handle by simple configuration in the logging module.